# Prevent creating empty Tar file in AIX Unix

Tags: unix, aix

I have a requirement to tar the files (in a single tar file)listed in a plain text file.

How can I prevent creating a tar file if the text file containing the file list is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Depend of the method how file is created you can have 0, 1 or more lines. If 0 all is clear, you have no files:

```
l=$(cat filelist.txt|wc -l)
if [ "$l" -eq 0 ]
then echo "No files in the list";exit 1
fi
```

if 1 it can be only enter or it can be only one file. You can check it on this way:

```
l=$(cat filelist.txt|wc -l)
if [ "$l" -eq 1 ]
then if [ ! -e $(cat filelist.txt) ] 
   then echo "No files in the list";exit 1
 fi
fi
```

If you want to make it on one line you can do something like:

```
tar xvf tarfile.tar `cat filelist.txt`|| rm tarfile.tar
```

or if you want to supress all the messages can be something like:

```
tar xvf tarfile.tar `cat filelist.txt` >/dev/null 2>&1|| rm tarfile.tar
```

This command will create tar file from `filelist.txt` and if something go wrong like empty list in file (or out of diskspace) will remove the tar file.

Comment: Thanks @Romeo ,so there is no one line TAR command to create the archived file only for non empty file?

Comment: @sqlpractice, did you try the idea from edited answer?